# WAMP MongoDB - PHP extension

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I have a problem with installation of MongoDB extension to PHP in WAMP SERVER.

The error that I obtain is show in photo[image]

Answer (score 6):

For the latest versions, we have to be careful about thread-safe version of the dll file too.

You can download latest dll from this link.
https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

[image]

And in this link, you have thread-safe and and non-thread-safe versions of .dll file.

[image]

if you have **php7ts.dll** or ts.dll file in your PHP installed directory you need to download that thread-safe dll file.

[image]

And after download you can add dll file to **\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\ext** directory and call inside php.ini file

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

That is telling you that you have not added the following line to the correct `php.ini` file

Use

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

to edit the CORRECT `php.ini` file.

Add your

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

with the other `extension` lines

If you have an extension line set in the correct `php.ini` file, then you need to ensure that the DLL with the same name is in the `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\ext` folder

Comment: in my php.ini i have this line : extension=php_mongo-1.5.1-5.5-vc11.dll

Comment: See additional info in the answer

Comment: I insert another photo

Answer (score 1):

One other piece of information on this:

- After you do "add extension=mongodb in bin->apache->apache(version)->bin->php.ini", you have to exit wampserver (right click the systray icon an choose exit) and restart it for it to "see" your change in the apache php file. Simply stopping and starting all services from the left click menu of wampserver does not refresh this new setting.

Answer (score 0):

add extension=mongodb  in bin->apache->apache(version)->bin->php.ini