# How to install mongodb with php 7.4.9 and WAMP with Apache 2.4.46 on Windows

Tags: php, mongodb, installation, wampserver

I try to install mongodb with PHP 7.4.9 and WAMP with Apache 2.4.46.

- I downloaded `php_mongodb-1.8.1-7.4-ts-vc15-x86` and copied `php_mongodb.dll` into `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\ext`
- then I add `extension=php_mongo.dll` in `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\bin\php.ini` and `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\php.ini`
- then I restart WAMP, but there is no module "mongodb" displayed in `phpinfo()`, but it is active in:

[image: wamp]

When I launch this code:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
```

There is an error :

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 3
( ! ) Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 3
```

Do you have any ideas how to make that work?

Comment: This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145401/wamp-mongodb-php-extension

Answer (score 0):

1. Download PHP MongoDB driver from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb)
2. Add DLL library path to your `php.ini` file as below

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

Also see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php) article

Your problem is `php_mongo.dll` and `php_mongodb.dll` are different libraries.

That is good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766586/fatal-error-class-mongodb-driver-manager-not-found)

OR

Just a setting mistake

> i downloaded php_mongodb-1.8.1-7.4-ts-vc15-x86 and copied
> php_mongodb.dll in "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\ext" then i add
> "extension=php_mongo.dll"

You copied `php_mongo`**db**`.dll` ans set `"extension=php_mongo.dll"`

Comment: Thanks,

i downloaded "php_mongodb-1.8.1-7.4-ts-vc15-x64" version 64 bit because my wamp install is in 64 bit then i copied the file php_mongodb.ddl in "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\ext" and i added in php.ini "extension=php_mongodb.dll" and it's worked.

Thanks a lot